# Protecting peers communicating with WebRTC

Tags: privacy, p2p

For reference: [WebRTC Homepage](http://www.webrtc.org/)

I've been really interested in these new RTC technologies that are coming out, specifically the fact that use the [PeerConnection API](http://www.webrtc.org/running-the-demos) to establish a connection between two browsers and receive media via P2P. So I have a few questions.

- What security measures can peers take to ensure their privacy and security when using technologies like this?
- Is there anything that a webmaster can do (programmatically or practically) to ensure peers are safe(r)?
- What risks are posed to peers in general?

Answer (score 1):

To state the obvious, you can serve your code over HTTPS.

The architecture diagram shows that it uses SRTP, the secure version of RTP.  It uses AES and HMAC-SHA1.

That leaves the question of key establishment for the SRTP session.  A quick search suggests this has been a sticky issue to standardize.  Clearly this is a goal of the project, but I don't know whether it's been settled yet, and whether there might be tradeoffs that you need to be aware of.  http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/rtcweb/current/msg04050.html

---

Also see (seems to be focused on issues about UI and granting permission) https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Discussions/WebRTC

> Security for WebRTC is (with no surprise) becoming a real rats-nest for some of the use-cases, such as screensharing ala WebEx, remote assistance ala Windows or VNC, ongoing permission ala Skype, etc.

---

The general impression is that, since WebRTC is an incomplete draft spec, information about its security is incomplete and drafty.

Comment: I'd add that from a design point of view, WebRTC is probably the most secure choice if you look at other VoIP options out there: http://bloggeek.me/webrtc-security/

Comment: @Tsahi I would make a comment on your blog (which is off-topic here), but it seems to think I'm a bot.  alan.christopher.jenkins@gmail.com